# Parse.com - Android does not receive Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I copy and paste from the tutorial:

Added following in my Application:

```
public void onCreate() {
    Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

which works, since i see the registered device on the web.

I added the following in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.emaborsa.cablePark.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.emaborsa.cablePark.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

        <category android:name="com.emaborsa.cablePark" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/park_logo_small"/>
```

But when i send a Push from the web, the Receiver is never called. Why?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Well, last week i tried again, i downloaded the newer version (1.8 instead of 1.7) and it worked... but now i have another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805645/parse-onpushopen-never-called/27806140?noredirect=1#comment44280761_27806140