# Parse onPushOpen never called

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the pushes using parse. added the parameters to the manifest file:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.emaborsa.cablePark.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Java code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String text = context.getResources().getString(R.string.msg_newDataEp);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.cableparks));

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    ((Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(500);

    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}


@Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);
}
```

I receive the pushes on all my test phones, but by clicking the notification the method onPushOpened is never called...
I need it for the Parse-Analytics.
The action `com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE` is fired since the method onPushReceive is called. `com.parse.push.intent.DELETE` and `com.parse.push.intent.OPEN` seem to never be fired, since the methods are never called...
Hints?

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/24949806/3310181

Comment: This link doesn't talk about `com.parse.push.intent.OPEN`...

Comment: Having the same issue here, were you ever able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution!

Add this in your getNotification()

```html
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
Random random = new Random();
int contentIntentRequestCode = random.nextInt();
int deleteIntentRequestCode = random.nextInt();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
Intent contentIntent = new Intent("com.parse.push.intent.OPEN");
contentIntent.putExtras(extras);
contentIntent.setPackage(packageName);
Intent deleteIntent = new Intent("com.parse.push.intent.DELETE");
deleteIntent.putExtras(extras);
deleteIntent.setPackage(packageName);
PendingIntent pContentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, contentIntentRequestCode, contentIntent, 0x8000000);
PendingIntent pDeleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, deleteIntentRequestCode, deleteIntent, 0x8000000);


Bitmap notificationLargeIconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
          new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
          .setLargeIcon(notificationLargeIconBitmap)
          .setContentIntent(pContentIntent).setDeleteIntent(pDeleteIntent)
          .setContentTitle(title)
          .setGroup("999")
          .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" +id))
          .setGroupSummary (true)
          .setContentText(text)
        //  .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
          .setNumber(++numMessages);
```

Basically we need to add both actions on your notificationbuilder.

Comment: ...i'll try when i touch the app again. Currently it is online and i will not release an update only for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution: Start **onPushOpen** using **Intent Filter from onPushReceive**

```
@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
      Intent i=new Intent("com.parse.push.intent.OPEN");

      PendingIntent resultPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

      int mNotificationId = 001;
      int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;



      NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);
      Notification mNotification = mBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setTicker("")
            .setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Heading")
            .setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText("Sample Notification"))
            .setSound(RingtoneManager                 .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setLargeIcon(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                            R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContentText(notification)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent).build();

      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, mNotification);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
       Log.d("TAG","Inside Push Open");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my working app looks like (and onPushOpen is definitely called) -

```
public class MyPushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Set a breakpoint or Log.
 }
}
```

And in my manifest -

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.xxx.yyy.MyPushReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Well...it is identical to mine. Do i have to add something else in the Application class? Actually i have only the  `Parse.initialize` and the `ParsePush.subscribeInBackground`

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: Currently using Parse-1.7.1.  How are you verifying that the method is definitely not called?

Comment: I put a Log.d and a breakpoint. Furthermore i don't see the analytics in the parse console.

Comment: i did some tests. The onPushOpen() is neither called. It seams that it recognizes my Receiver as a simple BroadcastReceiver insted of a  ParsePushBroadcastReceiver....

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // your code
    super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
}
```

call `super.onPushReceive(context, intent);` in `onPushReceive`

Comment: Doesn´t work. The point is that onPushOpen is never called...so it doesn't matter if i call the super or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the other answers worked partly.  Adding pushOpen to the pending intent did call onPushOpen.  However, you then need to start the activity you want in onPushOpen.

```
public void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // This is similar to an answer here...
    super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    Random random = new Random();
    int contentIntentRequestCode = random.nextInt();
    int deleteIntentRequestCode = random.nextInt();
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    Intent contentIntent = new Intent("com.parse.push.intent.OPEN");
    // You can pass some values to onPushOpen using extras
    contentIntent.putExtra("SOMEVALUEHERE", true);
    contentIntent.setPackage(packageName);
    Intent deleteIntent = new Intent("com.parse.push.intent.DELETE");
    deleteIntent.setPackage(packageName);
    PendingIntent pContentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, contentIntentRequestCode, contentIntent, 0x8000000);
    PendingIntent pDeleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, deleteIntentRequestCode, deleteIntent, 0x8000000);

    int iconToUse = R.drawable.YOURDRAWABLE;
    // Android M uses different style for icons BTW
    if (isAndroidM()) iconToUse = R.drawable.notification_icon;

    Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("YOURTITLE")
            .setContentText("YOURALERT")
            .setSmallIcon(iconToUse)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setContentIntent(pContentIntent).setDeleteIntent(pDeleteIntent)
            .build();

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, notif);
}

public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // I got a nullPointer on super, so I commented it for now
    //super.onPushOpen(context,intent);
    Log.d("TAG", "onPushOpen");
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);

    // Here is where you can open some activity based on your notifications
    if (intent.getBooleanExtra("SOMEVALUEHERE", false)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, YOURFIRSTCLASS.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, YOURCLASS2.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    } 
}
```